# Daterange picker when the html is added from javascript

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I am using the daterangepicker (http://www.daterangepicker.com/) and it is working fine when I apply it to '.dates'.

```
<input class="ff-text dates" type="text">
```

The following is used to make all dates classes to daterangepicker.

```
$('.dates').daterangepicker({
  "startDate": "02/15/2019",
  "endDate": "02/21/2019"
});
```

The problem occurs when the HTML is added through javascript.

```
<input class='ff-text dates' type='text'>
```

The HTML is added when a button is pressed, the HTML appears as it should, but the input field is not a daterangefield.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to re-run the daterangepicker when the html is added.  ideally, you should add an id to the new input, and run the daterangepicker against just that

e.g.

```
var someCounterForYourInputs = 0;
functionThatAddsYourHTML() {
    someCounterForYourInputs++;
    $('wherever-youre-adding').append($('<input id="sweet_dates_'+someCounterForYourInputs+'" class="ff-text dates" type="text"/>'));
    $('#sweet_dates_'+someCounterForYourInputs).daterangepicker({
        "startDate": "02/15/2019",
        "endDate": "02/21/2019"
    });
}
```

or alternately, no counters required:

```
functionThatAddsYourHTML() {
    var newInput = $('<input class="ff-text dates" type="text"/>');
    $('wherever-youre-adding').append(newInput);
    newInput.daterangepicker({
        "startDate": "02/15/2019",
        "endDate": "02/21/2019"
    });
}
```